# Angular setValue is not working on first call on primeng dropdown

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using angular **reactive forms** and **primeng dropdown**. When user select a customer I'm fetching customer data  and assigning `cityId` and `townId` properties of customer to primeng dropdown. Dropdown value lists are `cityList` and `townList` and  they are being fetched from an API and `townList` is being fetched according to  `cityList`. So   `cityId` is being assigned to dropdown correctly but `townId` is not being assigned if I don't select same customer again(The form value is not chaning)

```
 setCustomerInfo(customer: Customer) {
if (!this.orderMaster?.id) {
  this.form.get('billShipmentAddress').setValue(customer.address);
  this.form.get('billShipmentCityId').setValue(customer.cityId);
  this._comboService
  .getTownlist(customer.cityId)
  .subscribe((res)=>{
     this.townList = [...res]
     this.form.get("billShipmentTownId").setValue(customer.townId);
     console.log(this.form.value);
  })
  this.form.get('billShipmentPostCode').setValue(customer.postCode);
}}
```

This is the place where I  assign customer info to dropdowns. As you see I'm fetching `townList` with `getTownList` function.

Comment: qucik note: If I use `setTimeout` even without specifing any delay time to assign `townId` it's also working

Comment: I ran into a related issue. My [options] on my primeng <p-dropdown> can be dynamic, and after the options change, I was trying to set the new selected value using fromControl.setValue(). The value change was not taking effect until I did the change within a setTimeout. Seems like a hack...